# Performance tuning PORTB manipulation - mask

Tags: arduino-uno, port-mapping, performance

I have the following snippet that seems to be taking a total of 6 CPU cycles per invocation.

Can I speed this up somehow? `x`  is a byte with the 3 lowest bits set.

```
#define SET_COLOR(x) PORTB = (PORTB & ~(7)) | x
```

Comment: @TisteAndii: Interesting suggestion, but it ends up using an identical amount of instructions. I assume the compiler is smart enough.

Comment: @tisteandii compilers are smart enough to do this for you.

Comment: @Gerben So I gathered. Dont know much about the optimizations they perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 cycles:

```
IN Rd,PORTB
CBR Rd,7
ORI Rd,x
OUT PORTB,Rd
```

Translation into proper GCC inline assembly syntax is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks. In the end (with some proper analysis) it showed the original code was resulting in exactly 4 instructions, as well.